Is there any mathematical results stating when there are 0's in the inverse of a square matrix given 0's in the original matrix?
I am working with square invertible matrices. Denote the n-by-n matrix as $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Say we know that there are some 0's in the matrix. For instance: $A_{ij} = 0$ for some $i,j$ indices. Are there any results that state the inverse of the matrix $A^{-1}_{ij} = 0$ as well?
Here is a related result I found in Proposition 1 of the Appendix page 13 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.05052.pdf). It states:
Proposition 1. Consider a Markov network $M_Z$ over Z . Let $N_{Z_i}$ be the set of neighbors of $Z_i$ in $M_Z$, and A be an n × n
invertible matrix. For each $i \neq j$ where $Z_j$ is not adjacent to some nodes in $\{Z_i\} \cup N_{Z_i}$, suppose $A_{ij} = 0$. Then, we have
$A^{−1}_{ij} = 0$.
I am interested in if there is a more general linear algebra result that informs us when we can infer elements of the inverse of the matrix are 0.

There are more such linear algebra results, but mostly trivial ones. For example, it holds for upper-triangular invertible matrices (which is not a surprise).
